# Optional Attributes in Stored Procedure WHERE Clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an application in which a user can pass in some or all of the parameters I'm requesting to the application. (Basically, he or she can stop providing input to various pieces of data whenever they choose.) Based on the input they are providing, I want to get back information from a MS SQL 2008 database with only the parameters that they gave me.

I'm picturing something like this, but I can't seem to get it to work, and have no idea if it even can.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchForSolution]
    @Input1 int = 0, 
    @Input2 int = 0,
    @Input3 int = 0,
AS
SELECT Name, SolutionValue
FROM MyTable
WHERE (IF @Input1 != 0) { BETWEEN LowValue AND HighValue }
      AND (IF @Input2 != 0) { BETWEEN LowValue AND HighValue }
      AND (IF @Input3 != 0) { < HighValue }         
RETURN 0
```

Obviously, this isn't working code, but it gives the general idea. I want to be able to use a variable as part of the WHERE clause, but only if it is not using the magic number (which, in this case, is 0).

I am not very familiar with the capabilities of SQL here and am not sure if what I want to do is possible. Everything I have tried so far has failed. If I am completely going down the wrong path here, I would appreciate a pointer in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach...

```
 SELECT 
     Name, 
     SolutionValue
 FROM 
     MyTable
WHERE
     //Compact syntax simple for optional equals filter
     FIELD1  = ISNULL(@Input1,FIELD1) 
     //intention clearer and let's you do more than equals      
     AND ( @Input2 IS NULL OR FIELD2 > @Input2 ) 
     //can be extended for Between... 
     AND ((@Input3 IS NULL or  @Input4 IS NULL)   OR  FIELD3 BETWEEN  @Input3 AND @Input4 )
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
WHERE ( (@Input1 = 0) OR (@Input1 BETWEEN LowValue AND HighValue) )
  AND ( (@Input2 = 0) OR (@Input2 BETWEEN LowValue AND HighValue) ) 
  AND ( (@Input3 = 0) OR (@Input3 < HighValue) )
```

You can also change those `@InputX = 0` conditions to `@InputX IS NULL` if you want `0` to be available for use in the second checks.

Answer (score 0):

> A very common requirement in an information system is to have one or more functions where the users are able to search the data by selecting freely among many possible criterias. This is a tough challenge, because not only must you produce the desired output, but you must also keep the response time within acceptable limits, at least for common searches. And on top of all, the code must be maintainable, so that you easily can modify it to meet new needs and requirements.
>
> There are two ways to attack this problem: dynamic SQL and static SQL. Up to SQL 2005, it was difficult to find solutions for static SQL that were simple to write and maintain and yet performed well, and the recommendation was to use dynamic SQL. In SQL 2008, things changed. Microsoft changed the hint OPTION(RECOMPILE) so it now works as you would expect. However, there was a serious bug in the original implementation, and you need at least CU5 of SQL 2008 SP1 or SQL 2008 SP2 to benefit from this feature.

Erland Sommarskog has the definitive analysis of the various approaches to this problem and their respective pros and cons.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Some of the examples here will work just fine for smaller datasets, but I strongly encourage you check out that article.